# What to do with tag [prophet]

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [prophet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prophet) is intended to deal with questions dealing with the [Prophet application](http://www.prophet-web.com/prophet-products/) which was marketed by Sungard, now by FIS.

There is currently only one question (asked four years ago) that makes use of the tag, but many people (well, one a month or so) are incorrectly applying the tag to questions related to Facebook Prophet.

To avoid the confusion, would it be better to:

- rename the tag (perhaps to [fis-prophet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fis-prophet)) and possibly create a new tag ([fb-prophet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fb-prophet)?) to be used for Facebook Prophet questions?
- delete the tag from the one question using it and let the FB Prophet questioners claim the tag for their own use?
- do something else?

---

Note:  The Prophet application is licensed for an annual per-user fee which covers full support from the makers.  There is also a very small user base - probably less than 20,000 users world-wide - and most of those would only be end-users rather than "developers" (i.e. people building models rather than just using the models).  It is therefore very unlikely that there will ever be many future questions asked on Stack Overflow making use of the existing tag.

Comment: This: _delete the tag from the one question using it and let the FB Prophet questioners claim the tag for their own use_ seems logical to me if a problem arises. If you get tired of removing the tag from incorrectly tagged questions, then don't for a while, that way we can see the size of the problem (I really appreciate your work on the [tag:access] tag, though)

Answer (score 3):

I'm really not seeing a problem here.  If this tag were rampant with abuse, then we'd have an issue on our hands, but since there's only one question tagged with it, *and* it seems to be tagged correctly, I'm saying that there's no emergent problem here.

My recommendation would be to do **nothing**.  If a problem *does* arise, then we can deal with it.

Comment: I just get tired of having to remove the tag from incorrectly tagged questions.  Which is especially difficult when it is the only tag they use.  And given the number of incorrectly tagged questions, there seems to be a need for a [fb-prophet] tag (but I don't know enough about that subject to set up a tag with appropriate info).

Comment: How are these FB related questions are tagged now? Which tag is used?